# Conditional writing and parsing of files (if elif else)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'd like to parse some files and append any match to a dictionary. - **My regex does work, so no error here**...
*but* the files include some different formulations and I need to check for different regexes - I cant do this manually cause there are more than 10.000 files in my folder.

Anyways, I'd like to see if any of my regex matches. If so, I want to write the parsed file to a dict- that does work too - , BUT if **none** of my regex matches, I want to see the according file-name.. (appended to a list) ..

My issue: I dont know how to combine the if, elif and else statements accordingly.. So it should be like:

1. open the file and check first regex
2. if regex matches append to dictionary
3. if regex does not match, try second regex
4. if regex does match write to dict
5. if none of my regex match write file to list
   -- the last step is for me to check the formulation

So I read about it and tried:

```
files = ['C:/Users/file1.txt','C:/Users/file2.txt']
reg1 = r"some regex"
reg2 = r"some regex2"

error_list = []
dict_result = {}
for file in files:
  with open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8') as in_file:     
        content = in_file.read().lower()
        if re.match(reg1, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
            matches_reg1 = re.findall(reg1, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
            result = max(matches_reg1, key=len)
            result = str(result).replace('\n', '')
            dict_result["result"] = result
        elif re.match(reg2, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
            matches_reg2 = re.findall(reg2, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
            result = max(matches_reg2, key=len)
            result = str(result).replace('\n', '')
            dict_result["result"] = result
        else:
            error_list.append(file)
            print("ERROR: ", file)
```

But this absolutly does not work.. 
what did work better was this.. but it seems inefficient and does not show the error files, just the ones for the first regex:

```
for file in files:

  with open(file,'r', encoding='utf-8') as in_file:     
        content = in_file.read().lower()
        matches_reg1 = re.findall(reg1, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE) 
        matches_reg2 = re.findall(reg2, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

                if matches_reg1:
                    result = max(matches_reg1, key=len)
                    result = str(result).replace('\n', '')
                    dict_result["result"] = result
                if matches_reg2:

                    result = max(matches_reg2, key=len)
                    result = str(result).replace('\n', '')
                    dict_result["result"] = result
                else:
                    error_list.append(file)
                    print("ERROR: ", file)
```

... can someone explain an efficient way to deal with this? If I have a list of different regex approaches and like to check every regex until there is a match and otherwise write the file-path to a list for further analysis..

also tried..

```
matches_reg1 = re.findall(reg1,..)
if matches_reg1:
    ...
elif matches_reg1:
    match = re.findall(reg2, ...)
```

Comment: In what way(s) does the first code "absolutly does not work"?

Comment: Your code is missing some objects like the value of `name` and `files`.

Comment: The first code just shows the `else` statement... although, I know that the first regex should match some of the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to answer without additional details: could you provide the contents of the files ? Otherwise here is a generic answer based on what I understood of your intent: the key to debug your code is that `re.match` does not return a boolean, but returns either `None` (if no match) or a `SRE_Match` object (the first match, including its position).

So I would suggest that you rewrite your code as follows and put breakpoints to see what is captured in `matches_reg1` and `matches_reg2`.

```
content = in_file.read().lower()
matches_reg1 = re.match(reg1, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if matches_reg1:
    # do whatever you like here (i copied your original code)
    all_matches_reg1 = re.findall(reg1, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    result = max(all_matches_reg1, key=len)
    result = str(result).replace('\n', '')
    n_file.write(result)
else:
    matches_reg2 = re.match(reg2, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    if matches_reg2:
        # do whatever you like here (i copied your original code)
        all_matches_reg2 = re.findall(reg2, content, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
        result = max(all_matches_reg2, key=len)
        result = str(result).replace('\n', '')
        n_file.write(result)
    else:
        # do whatever you like here (i copied your original code)
        error_list.append(name)
        print("ERROR: ", name)
```

EDIT: you can also combine all of your regex with an "or" sign (`|`) inside a single regex so that you have a single if. To do this and to be able to disambiguate you would then need to ask the "match" object which group has matched. For example if you have two expressions to match "bli" and "bla" you can match both like this:

```
res = re.match("(bli)|(bla)", "blahbla")
```

and then you can do:

```
if res:
    # lets get the details of the matched expressions
    res_gr = res.groups()

    # act according to which group matched
    if res_gr[0]:
        # first expression matched
        ...
    elif res_gr[1]:
        # second expression matched
        ...
    else:
        raise Exception("should not happen")
else:
    # no match at all
```

As an additional tip I would highly recommend usage of https://regex101.com/ to debug the regular expressions outside of python first.

Comment: thanks, thats what I want. Is there an efficient way to check a list of different regexes? (as you can see above, I simplified my code for illustration)

Comment: you can also use a single regex with an "or" sign (`|`) so that you have a single if. I edited the answer accordingly.